# htaccess conflicting with wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I avoid editing the automated code by Wordpress because the changes may be erased and I'll have to do it all again. I have another site running the first three lines of code and it's working perfectly to replace *example.com* for *www.example.com*. That's all I really need for this *example.com* site but still preserving the Wordpress properties.

### The problem

*example.com* is not redirecting to *www.example.com* but instead displaying a 301 error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using the following lines in all my WordPress-Sites before the `# BEGIN WordPress`. This should solve your problem. The `L` (for last) is the solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It's now redirecting to the previous "under-construction" page that was named 'temp.html'.

Answer (score 1):

> "I avoid editing the automated code by Wordpress because the changes
>   may be erased and I'll have to do it all again."

You can avoid a WordPress installation from modifying its root `.htaccess` file.

Simply connect via FTP, or other means and chmod your WordPress root `.htaccess` file properties to `0444`.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the conflict? I can't see any conflict. WordPress only touches the lines after `# BEGIN WordPress`

Comment: I added a short description of the problem.